# How can we see the definition of system stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Iam trying to find the definition of system stored procedure sp_getapplock (). Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires membership in the public role.

sp_helptext sp_getapplock

```
create procedure sys.sp_getapplock --- 1999/04/14 00:00
 @Resource nvarchar (255) = NULL,           -- Resource to lock
 @LockMode varchar (32),                    -- Lock mode
 @LockOwner varchar (32) = 'Transaction',   -- Lock Owner - [D = Transaction]
 @LockTimeout int = NULL,                   -- Lock timeout [D = Session setting]
 @DbPrincipal sysname = N'public'       -- DB principal to use for name space and permissions
as

  declare @mode integer
  declare @owner integer
  declare @result integer
  declare @dbid integer

  select @mode =
   CASE @LockMode
     When ('Shared')            Then 3
     When ('Update')            Then 4
     When ('Exclusive')         Then 5
     When ('IntentExclusive')   Then 8
     When ('IntentShared')      Then 6
     Else -1
   END

  if @mode = -1
  begin
    raiserror(15625, -1, -1, @LockMode, N'@LockMode')
    return (-999)
  end

  select @owner =
   CASE @LockOwner
    When ('Transaction')    Then 1
    When ('Session')        Then 3
    Else -1
   END

  if @owner = -1
  begin
    raiserror(15625, -1, -1, @LockOwner, N'@LockOwner')
    return (-999)
  end

  if @LockTimeout is null
  begin
    set @LockTimeout = @@LOCK_TIMEOUT
  end

  select @dbid = db_id ()

  if @owner = 1 and @@trancount = 0
  begin
    raiserror(15626, -1, -1)
    return (-999)
  end

  exec @result = sys.xp_userlock 0, @dbid, @DbPrincipal, @Resource, @mode, @owner, @LockTimeout

  return @result
```

Comment: Added to the above question. How we can find the definition for sys.xp_userlock ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the definition of any stored procedure with **sp_helptext {stored procedure name}**.

Run below query:

```
sp_helptext sp_getapplock
```